# Hibernate, can't get data from relations

Tags: java, hibernate

Using Hibernate in my web application.
The database I'm using is :

```
User        Groupe      Groupes_Menus    Menu
UserID      GroupeID    GroupeID         MenuID
GroupeID                MenuID
Login
```

I'm trying to get all menus corresponding to one login.
I got 3 java classes :

User Groupe and Menu

User mapping :

```
@Id
@Column(name="USERID", nullable = false)
private int userID;

@Column(name = "LOGIN", length = 8, nullable = false)
private String login;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "GroupeID")
private Groupe groupe;
```

Groupe mapping :

```
@Id
@Column(name="GROUPEID", nullable = false)
private int groupeID;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "GROUPES_MENUS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GROUPEID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MENUID") })
private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>(0);
```

Menu mapping :

```
@Id
@Column(name="MENUID", nullable = false)
private int menuID;
```

Error I get is :

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entity.Groupe.menus, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: entity.User["groupe"]->entity.Groupe["menus"])
```

Not sure what is wrong in my code or anything, really beginner with hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@ManyToMany is Lazy be default.**

If you try to call *`getter` on this relation, outside the session/transaction*, it will throw the error. Within the same session/transaction calling *getter* will not cause any issue.

To overcome this issue, we can go with two options here.

1.) Making **`@ManyToMany` to Eager** instead of Lazy

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

** But this will always fetch eagerly, even if you do not require.

2.) **Initialize in Transaction** when needed.

```
 Hibernate.initialize(groupe.getMenus());
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ManyToMany` reltation is Lazy be default. You cannot get it outside the session.
Try to use `JOIN FETCH` in your query.
Also, you it's possibe to make you relation EAGER by default:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

But this is bad from performance POV.

Comment: @xNeyte you mean you comment these two lines, then they are still in session, not persisted to db

Comment: Well, the session remains opened. So, when you call `getMenus` the session is still active. But you need to close it when work is done.